# How to avoid late binding in this case?

Tags: vb.net, oop, binding

This is a one-class, one-form, pocket application that navigates to a particular website, logs in, and downloads files placed there for us. Everything was fine with just Chrome support, but users in our office can have Chrome or Firefox, so I had to accommodate that this way.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private browser As Object

    Private Sub doLogin()
        Me.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Logging in"
        If My.Settings.UserBrowser Is BrowserChrome Then
            Dim Options = New ChromeOptions
            'Set options
            Dim driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
            browser = New ChromeDriver(driverService, Options)
        Else
            Dim Options = New FirefoxOptions
            'Set options
            Dim driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
            browser = New FirefoxDriver(driverService, Options)
        End If
        browser.Url = "https://www.example.com"
        browser.Navigate()
```

Now, of course, `browser` is late-bound, but other than duplicating code for each browser all the way down, I don't know how to avoid late binding here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is the Selenium, then both FirefoxDriver and ChromeDriver have RemoteWebDriver as their base, but also have WebDriver as an Interface.

Which really is the important thing.

An interface gives you access to shared methods and properties, without needing to know the explicit version of class that's implemented. And interfaces are considered early bound, since method calls can be made without having to search through a list of possible candidate methods nor use System.Reflection to determine what the class can actually do.

```
Private browser As WebDriver

Private Sub doLogin()
    Me.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Logging in"
    If My.Settings.UserBrowser Is BrowserChrome Then
        Dim Options = New ChromeOptions
        'Set options
        Dim driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
        driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
        browser = New ChromeDriver(driverService, Options)
    Else
        Dim Options = New FirefoxOptions
        'Set options
        Dim driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
        driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
        browser = New FirefoxDriver(driverService, Options)
    End If
    browser.Url = "https://www.example.com"
    browser.Navigate()
    ' Do other things... 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When an object is dynamic or not known, which is your case, will only bind during runtime which is what you are seeing. Basically the compiler does not know what kind of object or the type of an object which contains methods & properties so it bypasses the compile-time checking. What you can do is cast this to it's appropriate type...

```
Private browser As Object = Nothing

Private Sub doLogin()
    Me.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Logging in"
    If My.Settings.UserBrowser Is BrowserChrome Then
        Dim Options = New ChromeOptions
        'Set options
        Dim driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
        driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
        browser = New ChromeDriver(driverService, Options)
    Else
        Dim Options = New FirefoxOptions
        'Set options
        Dim driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
        driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
        browser = New FirefoxDriver(driverService, Options)
    End If

    If TypeOf browser Is ChromeDriver Then
       CType(browser, ChromeDriver).Url = "https://www.example.com"
       CType(browser, ChromeDriver).Navigate()
    ElseIf TypeOf browser Is FirefoxDriver Then
       CType(browser, FirefoxDriver).Url = "https://www.example.com"
       CType(browser, FirefoxDriver).Navigate()
    End If

End Sub
```

Or another possibility...

```
 CType(browser, If(TypeOf browser Is ChromeDriver, ChromeDriver, FirefoxDriver)).Url = "https://www.example.com"
 CType(browser, If(TypeOf browser Is ChromeDriver, ChromeDriver, FirefoxDriver)).Navigate()
```